# SQL Business Day comparison of two dates

Tags: sql, date

I have researched some calendar tables that I thought would help me accomplish what I need but can't seem to find anything.  What I need is a business day comparison month over month.  Say today is 4/29/2015.  we will just call it business day 20.  What date in the prior month compares to business day 20 for march.  Any thoughts on the approach?  Thank you everyone.

Comment: Create a map of business day and calendar date i.e. a Table with two columns Business_Day and Calendar_Date

Comment: @bjan's comment is spot on. This is more of a business intelligence thing, rather than something procedural. Factor in such things as holidays not being business days, special celebrations like "Founder's Day - We are closed", etc., and you see that you do need a table for this.

Comment: So I manually need to account for each related date correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date or calendar table is what you are looking for here.  I'm not sure where you couldn't 'seem to find anything', though.  Date tables can be custom suited to whatever your business needs are.  Some need only a few extra fields, some use many extra fields.

You'll need to account for any holidays, also.  Does Memorial Day count as a business day?  Are you open on MLK Jr day?  Holidays vary from country to country, company to company, you name it.  I would definitely get some of the powers that be involved to help you out in identifying what constitutes a 'workday'.

Here's a few articles that will get you on the road, unfortunately, none of us will be able to just built it for you as you need to dicuss that with the stakeholders in the business.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12267/Build-your-own-SQL-calendar-table-to-perform-complex-date-expressions.html

http://www.sqlserver.info/database-design/how-to-create-a-date-table/

Comment: Please don't link to sites like experts exchange that have a login wall

Comment: We are closed on MLK day.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting a login wall, goes right in for me (and no, I'm not logged into the site, nor have I ever registered for it)

Comment: @aaron You'll need to account for that when you build it.  Also consider Pittsburgh DBA's recommendations.

Comment: Ok I think I have my path now.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed my solution and wanted to share.  What I would up doing was building a Calendar table and labeled "workdays".  This excluded weekends and holidays.  After that table was completed I used the Rank function and ranked each day over partition [Month], [Year] and Ordered by day.  Then just created a field on the Calendar table and Updated the field with

```
UPDATE Auxiliary.Calendar
SET BusDayOfMonth = b.NewRanking
FROM Auxiliary.Calendar a INNER JOIN
         (SELECT date, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Month, Year ORDER BY Day ASC) AS NewRanking FROM Auxiliary.Calendar WHERE KindOfDay = 'BANKDAY') b ON a.date = b.date
```

Now I have a field that shows me which business day ID each date in the month is for any date.  Thank you everyone for your suggestions.